# Get build number using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Facing issue with jenkins job

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method jenkins.model.ParameterizedJobMixIn$ParameterizedJob scheduleBuild2 int hudson.model.Action[]
```

Heere is the code to get Build number

```
def var= job.scheduleBuild2(0, new ParametersAction(params))
            anotherBuild = var.get()
          println HyperlinkNote.encodeTo('/' + anotherBuild.url, anotherBuild.fullDisplayName,**anotherBuild.getNumber().toString()**) + " completed. Result was " + anotherBuild.result
```

getNumber to get build of another job is it right ? how can I get build Number of downstream job in groovy

Comment: `getNumber()` is indeed returns the build number of job triggered. But exception you are facing looks something different, may be try to approve this particular script from Navigate to jenkins > Manage jenkins > In-process Script Approval and try again

Comment: yeah but its not hyperlinked